# Rights of EU/EC permanent residents - can I formally move?

Tags: germany, eu, eu-citizens, residency

I'm a permanent resident of an EU member state, but not yet a citizen of that country as the process will take another year or so (bureaucracy, sigh). So, I don't think I qualify as an "EU national" and am unsure what my status is if I want to formally move to another EU country... Since I am self-employed and not bound to an office, I've been spending most of my time outside of my country of residency rather informally for over a year now (dealing with local landlords, or AirBNB, never bothering to register with local authorities), but now I'd like to relocate to Berlin for the near future, and do it properly, and I see it is rather hard to do much of anything without an Anmeldung (open a bank account, get my own Internet connection, etc...).

Most posts I find are about "working in Germany as an EU resident" etc... but I think my case is a little different. Am I eligible to apply for an Anmeldung, or am I going to have to live the hapless AirBNB lifestyle for another year or so?

Edit: I did find this, and it seems promising:
https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/325475/en/

Comment: You should be careful. Some countries will revoke your PR if you stay outside the country too long (if you're caught).

Comment: Moreover, if you get caught living and working (yes, even self employment) in another country without permission, you're in for a world of bad news.

I'd stay put till I got citizenship.

Comment: Plus, some countries acquired citizenship is tied to you intent to live in that country, and might be revoked of you move elsewhere shortly after you get it.

Comment: @lafemmecosmique according to the directive, status can be lost on the ground of absence only after absence from the EC for a period of 12 consecutive months or from the granting state for six years, but having permanent residence in the EU (other than UK, Denmark, or Ireland) entitles the OP to residence in Germany.

Comment: Oh, ok. I didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: @lafemmecosmique neither did I!  That's one of the benefits of stackexchange.

Answer (score 5):

Your edit seems to have answered your question, and the answer is *yes.*  The relevant directive is [2003/109/EC](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02003L0109-20110520).

It gives you a right to a residence permit in Germany, unless your current country of residence is the United Kingdom, Denmark, or Ireland.  These three countries have not implemented the directive.

During your period of temporary residence in Germany, you retain your status as a permanent resident of the original country.